# El valor de una variable no se me cambia cuando la actualizo

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, lógica

Tengo un problema cuya solución no he encontrado en otras preguntas realizadas, que se me antoja básico y que, a mí ver, debería funcionar.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div id="uno">
      
</div>

<script>

      addOp=document.getElementById("uno");
      a=1;
      contador=4;
    
    if (a<contador){
      addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="boton()"></input>');
      addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ' ' + a);
      
    }
    
    function boton(){
     
    
      a=++;
      return a;
    
    }

</script>
```

Lo que necesito que se haga lo siguiente:

- Mientras `a` sea menor que `contador`, me imprime un botón.
- El botón llama a la función `botón` cuando se hace `click`.
- La función botón aumenta en `1` el valor de `a` y cuando `a` sea mayor que `contador`, deja de imprimir el botón en el div.

El problema es que no actualiza la variable. Sí la actualiza si haces dentro de la función `boton` un `alert` o imprimes el valor de `a`, pero en cuanto sale de esa función y vuelve al código, a vuelve a valer 1.

Un `for` o un `while` no me sirven, pues debe imprimirse cada vez que se hace click y se comprueba la condición. A mi entender el código es correcto, pero debe de haber algo que se me escapa.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás esperando que se actualice la vista cuando el modelo se modifica, pero eso no ocurre automáticamente, tienes que hacerlo tú:

```js
const addOp=document.getElementById("uno");
let a=1;
let contador=4;
addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="boton()"></input>');
addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ' ' + a);


function boton(){
  a++;
  if (a<contador){
    addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ' ' + a);
  }
  return a;
}
```

```html
<div id="uno">
          
    </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas. Ambos me habéis ayudado mucho. Sabía que había algún error de lógica en mi planteamiento pero no veía cuál era. El "a=++" fue un fallo mío al escribir aquí el código, pero al margen de eso, tenéis ambos razón. 
De veras, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código presenta varios problemas:

- Deberías definir el tipo de variable para `addOp`, `a` y `contador`.
- El "control" (`a < contador`) solo lo realizas cuando se inicia el proceso.
- La expresión `a=++;` presenta un error de sintaxis.

#### Solución:

- Podrías mover el "control" de `a < contador` a una función llamada `control` (*por ejemplo*).
- Cuando inicias llamas a `control()` y cada vez que se ejecuta la función `botón`

```js
let addOp = document.getElementById("uno"),
  a = 1,
  contador = 4;

function controlar() {
  if (a < contador) {
    addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="boton()"></input>');
  }
  addOp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ' ' + a + '<br>');
}

function boton() {
  a++;
  controlar();
}

controlar();
```

```html
<div id="uno"></div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. Valga este comentario como complementario del de abajo. No me dejó marcaros a ambos.